# Mysql Workbench Reverse Engineer function doesn't generate relationship "Lines" between tables

Tags: mysql-workbench

I just get a new project that need to work with a DB nobody knows about the structure about it. It is on the Mysql DB so I tried to use mySQL Workbench to export EER Diagram from this DB by using the Reverse Engineer function as many others recommended

I did get tables from the DB...but JUST tables!! no relationship that is the lines connect tables. Did I do something wrong or it is just because the ER Diagram from MySql Workbench is supposed to be like that?

Can anyone recommend tools that can export ER Diagram from existed DB? Include the relationship lines...

Comment: Facing the same problem where.

Answer (score 1):

Relationships are only shown for foreign keys (how could MySQL Workbench otherwise know). If your tables have no foreign keys (e.g. because they are still using the MyIASM table engine instead of InnoDB) you won't get any relationships.